# Find which file is providing the proxy settings to a host

Tags: linux, proxy

A Fedora system shows incorrectly configured proxy settings on boot. I need to figure out which file has those wrong proxy settings.

I checked ~/.bashrc and ~/.bash_profile but they don't have those settings. Where else can they be?

Comment: Have you tried `grep -r <proxy-setting> /etc/` ?

Answer (score 0):

Do the following:

```
grep -rnw '/path/to/somewhere/' -e 'pattern'
```

- -r or -R is recursive,
- -n is line number, and
- -w stands for match the whole word.
- -l (lower-case L) can be added to just give the file name of matching files.

Along with these, --exclude, --include, --exclude-dir flags could be used for efficient searching

OR

You can use grep -ilR:

```
grep -Ril "text-to-find-here" /
```

- i stands for ignore case (optional in your case).
- R stands for recursive.
- l stands for "show the file name, not the result itself".
- / stands for starting at the root of your machine.

source:

[How do I find all files containing specific text on Linux? on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16956810/how-do-i-find-all-files-containing-specific-text-on-linux)